# ApexCharts Column Chart Markers Broken?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I can't get the "markers" to show when I try the demo code for [ApexCharts Column with Markers](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/column-charts/column-with-markers/). Can't figure out why. Assuming it might be on their end. Need to add some more text here, but they provide demos for Angular, React, and Vue too, those seem to work (haven't tried the Vue one). I also checked the documentation, but could not find anything on it.

```js
var options = {
  series: [
    {
      name: "Actual",
      data: [
        {
          x: "2011",
          y: 1292,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 1400,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2012",
          y: 4432,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 5400,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2013",
          y: 5423,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 5200,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2014",
          y: 6653,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 6500,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2015",
          y: 8133,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 6600,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2016",
          y: 7132,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 7500,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2017",
          y: 7332,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 8700,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          x: "2018",
          y: 6553,
          goals: [
            {
              name: "Expected",
              value: 7300,
              strokeWidth: 5,
              strokeColor: "#775DD0",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: "bar",
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      columnWidth: "60%",
    },
  },
  colors: ["#00E396"],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  legend: {
    show: true,
    showForSingleSeries: true,
    customLegendItems: ["Actual", "Expected"],
    markers: {
      fillColors: ["#00E396", "#775DD0"],
    },
  },
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I was using an old installation and redoing that fixed it.
https://apexcharts.com/docs/installation/